# Cannot adjust Tizen wearable emulator's clock

Tags: time, emulation, tizen

On Tizen's wearable emulator, how can one change the date and time of the watch (Gear S2 for me)? I cannot seem to find anywhere to do so. I even went into the shell and issued "date" command yet permission denied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**From sdb shell you can change date/time in root mode only.**

Once the emulator is started. **Right click** on the emulator and select '**Shell**' from the option which will open the sdb shell in user(**$**) mode. Please run **su** command to go to root(**#**) mode. Then run below command on the shell to change the date/time

**date --set="3 JAN 2016 18:00:00"**

Comment: What is the password for the root? I didn't set any when creating an emulator device...

Comment: I know I'm a bit late here but the default password for the Tizen emulator is tizen. You can access the the root mode on the shell using the command:

_su #_